# could not initialize proxy - no Session Spring data jpa + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

**UPDATE**

Попробовал сделать `REST` запрос и все работает на отлично. Магия. Но в чем причина того бага?

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/category/load", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private Response categoryLoad(Response response, @RequestBody CategoryLoadForm categoryLoad) {

        Category category = categoryService.getById(categoryLoad.getCategoryId());

        if(category!=null) {
            LOGGER.info(category);
            response.setSuccess("OK");
            response.addData("images", imageService.getAllByCategoryId(category.getId()));
        } else {
            response.setError("Китегория не найдена");
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Проблема возникает тут:

```
Category category = categoryService.getById(id);

if(category!=null) {
    title = "Панель управления - Категория "+category.getName();
    ...
}
```

Уже пробовал разные решение которые предлагали:

`hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`
убирать `FetchType.LAZY`, ставить `EAGER`

Не помогает ничего. в чем беда? При чем получается в сущности все поля `null`, Хотя до этого я нигде запросов не делал.

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = {@ComponentScan("com.site.service")})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.site.dao")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lcemfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        lcemfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        lcemfb.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        lcemfb.setPackagesToScan("com.site.entity");
        lcemfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return lcemfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("database.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", env.getProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode"));
        properties.put("hibernate.enable.lazy.load.on.trans", env.getProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_on_trans"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Secured("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/panel")
public class PanelController {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigService configService;

    @Autowired
    private ImageService imageService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @GetMapping(value = {"", "/", "/index"})
    private ModelAndView index(ModelAndView view, HttpServletRequest request) {
        view.addObject("title", "Панель управления");
        view.setViewName("panel/index");
        return view;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/pages")
    private ModelAndView main(ModelAndView view) {
        view.addObject("title", "Панель управления - Страницы");
        view.setViewName("panel/pages");
        return view;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/categories", "/categories/{id}"})
    private ModelAndView categories(ModelAndView view, @PathVariable(required = false) Integer id) {

        String title = "Панель управления - Категории";

        if(id!=null) {

            Category category = categoryService.getById(id);

            if(category!=null) {
                title = "Панель управления - Категория "+category.getName();
                view.getModelMap().addAttribute("images", imageService.getAllByCategoryId(category.getId()));
            } else {
                title= "Панель управления - Категория не найдена";
            }
        }

        view.getModelMap().addAttribute("title", title);

        view.getModelMap().addAttribute("scripts", new String[]{"panel/categories.js"});
        view.getModelMap().addAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAll());
        view.setViewName("panel/categories");

        return view;

    }

}
```

Category:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "preview")
    private String preview;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private String created;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public Category() { }

    public Category(String name, String description, String preview) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.preview = preview;
    }

    // getters, setters
}
```

CategoryService:

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CategoryService.class);

    public List<Category> getAll() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Category getById(int id) {
        return categoryRepository.getOne(id);
    }

}
```

CategoryRepository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

}
```

Вся ошибка:

```
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.site.entity.Category#1] - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:159) [hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:272) [hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:52) [hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) [hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
        at com.site.entity.Category$HibernateProxy$eWyxRGT3.getName(Unknown Source) [classes/:?]
        at com.site.controller.PanelController.categories(PanelController.java:60) [classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.

security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать, все что связанно с lazy и поставьте eager...какая там ошибка получается?

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov пробовал уже и то и то и убирал вообще (Хотя по умолчанию LAZY). Одна и та же ошибка всегда. Думал что может проект не пересобрался - пересобирал, но все равно ошибка. И именно в том месте. в REST запросе такого нет.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать проперти hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans поставить eager, и вызвать метод не getOne, а findById

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov добр человек. Ты бог просто. заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тогда пример использования без него:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>home.hibernate.crudrepository</groupId>
    <artifactId>home.hibernate.crudrepository</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <spring-framework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

DBConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("home.hibernate.crudrepository.com")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="home.hibernate.crudrepository.com.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lcemfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        lcemfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        lcemfb.setPersistenceUnitName("myJpaPersistenceUnit");
        lcemfb.setPackagesToScan("home.hibernate.crudrepository.com");
        lcemfb.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return lcemfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
        JpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("database.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(
                entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Status.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "statuses")
public class Status {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "status", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
        user.setStatus(this);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        users.remove(user);
        user.setStatus(null);
    }

}
```

User.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_status")
    private Status status;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

StatusRepository.class:

```
@Repository
public interface StatusRepository extends CrudRepository<Status, Integer> {
}
```

UserRepository.class:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Application.class:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DBConfig.class);
        UserRepository userRepository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
        StatusRepository statusRepository = context.getBean(StatusRepository.class);

        Status status = new Status();
        status.setStatus("status1");

        status = statusRepository.save(status);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("user1");
        status.addUser(user);

        userRepository.save(user);

        System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
        System.out.println(statusRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```

Comment: обновил Выше информацию. Тот же самый код который у меня работает при REST запросе. И у меня крашится именно на получении элемента по ID. А так спасибо за пример.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вариант с Springboot:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>home.springboot.data.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa=many-to-many</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Order.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "orders_products",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_order")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_product")}
    )
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();

    public Order() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.getOrders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.getOrders().add(this);
    }

}
```

Product.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

    public Product() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

}
```

OrderRepository.class:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Integer> {
}
```

ProductRepository.class:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {
}
```

Application.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setName("product1");
        product1 = productRepository.save(product1);

        Order order1 = new Order();
        order1.setName("order1");
        order1.addProduct(product1);
        orderRepository.save(order1);

        System.out.println(orderRepository.findAll());
        System.out.println(productRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```

Comment: Spring Boot хорошо, но требование заказчика его не использовать. Увы.